# VHDL elegant way of implementing a select with don't care condition in the input

Tags: vhdl

[image: select]I am quite new to VHDL and I was wondering if there would be an elegant way of implementing a do not care condition with a select statement. It seems way to tedious to go ahead and list all possibilities for the do not care.

Comment: Use - for don’t care. See the definition of std_logic [here](https://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00067.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VHDL-2008 or newer you can use a "-" as don't care in a select statement if your synthesizer implements this feature.

See UG901 (Vivado Design Suite User Guide) page 217.
https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2019_1/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf

```
process(clk) begin
  if clk’event and clk=’1’ then
    with my_reg select?
      out1 <= 
      in1 when “11--“,
      in2 when “000-“,  
      in3 when “1011”,
      in4 when others;
  end if;
end process;
```

Here is the results of running the above select-statement code through the synthesizer in Vivado 2018.2
[image]

If your synthesizer doesn't support using don't cares and your number of cases is reasonably small then just use an if statement to achieve the same result.  The above example could be transformed into the following.

```
process(clk) begin
  if clk’event and clk=’1’ then
    if my_reg(3 downto 2) = "11" then
      out1 <= in1;
    elsif my_reg(3 downto 1) = "000" then
      out1 <= in2;
    elsif my_reg(3 downto 0) = "1011" then
      out1 <= in3;
    else
      out1 <= in4;
    end if;        
  end if;
end process;
```

Here is the results of running the above if-statement code through the synthesizer in Vivado 2018.2

[image]

As you see, the Vivado synthesizer on default settings generated the exact same result for both sets of code.  This is not surprising because they are logically equivalent.

Comment: If synthesiser doesn't support "don't cares", it's much better to write down the complete case statement. Because nested-if like this may synthesise to a priority-based combi network which degrades the performance.

Comment: @MituRaj  agree with that to a point.  While using nested if statements can result in more levels of logic, it often doesn't.  I have typically found that on LUT based FPGAs (which is nearly all of them) any statement involving a number of inputs that is less than the native LUT size will just get packed into a single LUT, no matter how you write it.  On a Xilinx 7-series part, anything less than 6 inputs almost always just turns into one LUT no matter how you write it.  Its not really an issue until you find yourself not meeting timing.

Comment: @MituRaj Also fewer lines of code is easier to type and easier for other people to read.  If I had 10 inputs, I might not be willing to type out all 1024 cases, and someone reading it might not make sense of the 1024 lines of code.  If the code is meeting timing; then its sometimes worth it to trade a little performance for the sake of readability.

Comment: Lines of code doesn't matter in HDL like in C or C++. I can write a 100 lines of code in HDL and 10 lines of code in HDL with same functionality but end up with better timing performance in the first one. People prefer only the first one. None wants a "shorter" code which performs poorly in hardware.

Comment: Maybe some synthesisers are too "clever". But as a generic coding guideline what you have written is bad style of coding and you can see that if you check HDL coding guidelines from lattice/xilinx/altera. They always say implement a full case rather than nested-ifs

Comment: @MituRaj I ran both sets of code through the Vivado Synthesizer on default settings and the results were identical.

Comment: Also in VHDL-2008, you can write `process(all)`. This prevents bugs due to simulator/synthesis mismatches caused by the sensitivity list diverging from what is written in the block of code.